# PHP: Replace ID with string, based on decoded JSON number

Tags: php, json, wordpress, string, if-statement

The custom Wordpress plugin I installed, responsible for all kind of hotel booking requests, displays a calendar containing the for- and surname of our clients in the Wordpress backend. At first I didn't get the ID of the booked apartment, but now I got that which leads me to the next problem.

Unfortunately only the ID of the booked apartment is displayed in the backend. Is there a way to convert the ID into a predefined string before the page is displayed?

Like `237` » `Apartment 4`?

I already tried it with a If-condition, but nothings happened.

```
if ( !empty($booked_ids) ) {

    foreach( $booked_ids as $key => $val) {

        echo '<tr class="sh_booking_data">';

            $booking_meta = get_post_meta( $val, '_booking_meta', true );

            $arr = json_decode($booking_meta["save_rooms"], true);

            die($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"]);

            if ( $arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 237 ) {
                $bodytag = "Apartment 4";
                echo("<script>console.log('PHP: " . $arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] . "');</script>");    
            }

            echo '<td><a href="' . get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=booking_add&booking=' . $val . '">#' . $val . ' ' . $booking_meta["first_name"] . ' ' . $booking_meta["last_name"] . ' ' . $arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] . '</a></td>';

            foreach( $month_1_2_array as $key => $val) {

                if ( !empty($booking_meta["booking_status"]) ) {    
                    if ( $booking_meta["booking_status"] == 1 ) {       
                        $booking_status_class = 'pending';  
                    } elseif ( $booking_meta["booking_status"] == 2 ) {
                        $booking_status_class = 'confirmed';
                    } elseif ( $booking_meta["booking_status"] == 3 ) {
                        $booking_status_class = 'cancelled';
                    } else {    
                        $booking_status_class = 'unknown';  
                    }
                } else {
                    $booking_status_class = 'unknown';
                }

                if( $booking_meta["check_in"] == $val ) {
                    echo '<td class="sh_first_day_' . $booking_status_class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
                } elseif( $booking_meta["check_out"] == $val ) {
                    echo '<td class="sh_last_day_' . $booking_status_class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
                } elseif ( sh_get_date_range_overlap($val,$val,$booking_meta["check_in"],$booking_meta["check_out"]) == true ) {
                    echo '<td class="sh_booking_' . $booking_status_class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                }

            }

        echo '</tr>';

    }

}
```

I'm very new to PHP and thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have an array with the id as the index and the string as the value

Comment: **Note**: you are not `echo` the output correctly. You have opened a <span> tag and not closed it, also you have closed an </a> tag, but you haven't opened it. I have removed the </a> tag and closed the <span> tag in **my answer's code script**

Comment: Please look for the updated code snippet. It's fixed now. But I think $bodytag will not be updated because 'the code' is further then this line. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got  multiple IDs, then you can list all the available IDs in `if-else` block and assign the relevant `Apartment name` for the relevant ID to the `$bodytag`, so you can use `$bodytag` to print `echo` it.

So below is an example:

Assuming that you have 6 ID's which are `237`, `27`, `251`, `252`, `255`, and `260`, so you put all of them in `if-else` block like this and assign the relevant apartment name for the relevant ID.

```
$bodytag = ""; // initialize the variable 
if ($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 237) {
    $bodytag = "Apartment 4";
}
else if ($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 27) {
     $bodytag = "Apartment 10";
}
else if ($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 251) {
     $bodytag = "Apartment 12";
}
else if ($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 252) {
     $bodytag = "Apartment 13";
}
else if ($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] == 255) {
     $bodytag = "Apartment 15";
}
else{
     $bodytag = "Apartment 20";
}

echo '<td><a href="' . get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=booking_add&booking=' . $val . '">#' . $val . ' ' . $booking_meta["first_name"] . ' ' . $booking_meta["last_name"] . ' ' . $bodytag  . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your approach does not work, no value is output.

Comment: @dmnktoe, when you run this script, is that comes into the `true` block?

Comment: @dmnktoe then your php.ini is incorrectly configured. make sure `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `display_errors=On` in php.ini while developing, then you will get output from @Kaz's code.

Comment: @dmnktoe *note*: you are not `echo` the output correctly. You have opened a `<span>` tag and not closed it, also you have closed an `</a>` tag, but you haven't opened it. I have removed the `</a>` tag and closed the `<span>` tag in my answer's code script.

Comment: I updated my code snippet, so you can see that I properly inserted your recommendation, but still nothing happens.

Comment: @dmnktoe, I already asked you that When you run this script, is that comes into the true block? if you do not know how to check it, you can put `die('comes here');` at the bottom of the `$bodytag` variable and run your code. If you get the `comes here` as the output in the browser, then it means it comes to the `true` block. you have to check it, then only i can give you solutions.

Comment: @Kaz I just added a `console.log` right into the `if-condition` which won't be executed. I think its an equivalent to your `die`.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of equivalent to `die`, but there's a difference between them. That is if you put `die` in a php script, the code will stop executing right after that.

Comment: @dmnktoe,It seems the `room_type` is not `237`, that is why it does not come to the `true` block, so before that condition put `die($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"])`, and check the output, and let me know.

Comment: @dmnktoe, do you have many apartment IDs or only one which is `237`?

Comment: @Kaz I got multiple IDs and `237` is definitely one of them. I know that because I successfully logged it already. I think the if condition code-block is executed to early, so the values doesn't get updated.

Comment: @dmnktoe did you check what you get for the `die($arr["Room 1"]["room_type"]);`. You have to put it before the `if condition`. Because I want to make sure that you index the ID form $arr["Room 1"]["room_type"] correctly

Comment: I updated the code in my question and put the `die` into it. Now, it displays the first element of the array containing the number of the apartment. In this case apartment ID `27`: https://imgur.com/kYKBkpQ - but there are multiple bookings available, so there should be more bookings.

Comment: Glad to help you :)